# Automatically Refreshing <div>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a piece of code that automatically refreshes every 5 seconds. It is not working, I have no clue why. I have been looking for a few hours now.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#songname').load('<?php include_once 'http://api.flare-radio.com/php/song/' ;?>', function(){
        setInterval(function(){

        }, 5000);

    });
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="song container">
        <div id="songname"></div>
        <br/>
        <h2 class="song">Presenter: <?php include_once 'http://api.flare-radio.com/php/presenter/' ;?></h2>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <audio id="radioplayer" src="http://srv.flare-radio.com:8000/stream" autoplay></audio><input id="volume" name="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" type="range" onchange="setVolume()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The function you pass to `setInterval()` is empty, so obviously it won't do anything. What happens if you move the `$('#songname').load()` code to *inside* the `setInterval()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you want to do every 5 seconds needs to be inside the function you deliver as an argument to setInterval.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('stream_path.php', function(data)  { //maybe adjust path to php file
            $("#songname").html(data);
        }, 'text');
    }, 5000);
 }
```

**Edit:** above and below

Check code snippet above for adjustment.
I would recommend to use the **get** function of jQuery and return the data from additional php file (doesn't work directly from js because js is on clients side. php runs on server)

So my final solution (checked it and worked for me)

**Javascript:**

-see above

**stream_path.php:**

```
$url = 'http://api.flare-radio.com/php/song/';
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

**html content:**

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="song container">
        <div id="songname"><?php echo file_get_contents('http://api.flare-radio.com/php/song/'); ?></div>
        <br>
        <h2 class="song">Presenter: <?php echo file_get_contents('http://api.flare-radio.com/php/presenter/') ;?></h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <audio id="radioplayer" src="http://srv.flare-radio.com:8000/stream" autoplay></audio><input id="volume" name="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" type="range" onchange="setVolume()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I added that code, how ever it doesn't go into the div.

Comment: So, the new code you made works, but when I go to the page it takes a few seconds to load. Is their any way of making that instant?

Comment: @LukeHallett Of Course. Just adjust the line in your html where you load the song title at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
    setInterval(function(){
   $('#songname').load('<?php include_once 'http://api.flare-radio.com/php/song/' ;?>' 
 }, 5000);
```